# AWS Elemental MediaConvert: mov file is not supported

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-elemental

I wanna overlay a movie (.mov) on top of another movie (.mp4), using AWS Elemental MediaConvert.

I uploaded one .mov file and one .mp4 to S3, both have similar dimensions.

In AWS Elemental MediaConvert, I created a job:

- Input: .mp4 file
- Motion image inserter: .mov file
- Output file will be an mp4 file

Result: the job is failed, error message:

```
MGILoaderMOV [s3://test/overlay.mov] file contains unsupported pixel format.
```

The .mov file is working fine because I can play it from my laptop, IAM includes Full access to your Amazon S3 resources.

Any suggestion is appreciated

***** More detail *****

@Tiziano Coroneo, I got a new overlay.mov (converted from FFmpeg, dimension (450x450)). I set up the output as below:

- Preprocessors: Input cropping rectangle X(100), Y(100), Width(450), Height(450)

The job is executed successfully, but the output doesn't include the overlay.

```
    {
  "Queue": "arn:aws:mediaconvert:yyyyyyy:xxxxxxxx:queues/Default",
  "UserMetadata": {},
  "Role": "arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxxxxxx:role/my_media_role",
  "Settings": {
    "OutputGroups": [
      {
        "Name": "File Group",
        "Outputs": [
          {
            "ContainerSettings": {
              "Container": "MP4",
              "Mp4Settings": {
                "CslgAtom": "INCLUDE",
                "FreeSpaceBox": "EXCLUDE",
                "MoovPlacement": "PROGRESSIVE_DOWNLOAD"
              }
            },
            "VideoDescription": {
              "ScalingBehavior": "DEFAULT",
              "Crop": {
                "Height": 450,
                "Width": 450,
                "X": 100,
                "Y": 100
              },
              "TimecodeInsertion": "DISABLED",
              "AntiAlias": "ENABLED",
              "Sharpness": 50,
              "CodecSettings": {
                "Codec": "H_264",
                "H264Settings": {
                  "InterlaceMode": "PROGRESSIVE",
                  "NumberReferenceFrames": 3,
                  "Syntax": "DEFAULT",
                  "Softness": 0,
                  "GopClosedCadence": 1,
                  "GopSize": 90,
                  "Slices": 1,
                  "GopBReference": "DISABLED",
                  "SlowPal": "DISABLED",
                  "SpatialAdaptiveQuantization": "ENABLED",
                  "TemporalAdaptiveQuantization": "ENABLED",
                  "FlickerAdaptiveQuantization": "DISABLED",
                  "EntropyEncoding": "CABAC",
                  "Bitrate": 1000000,
                  "FramerateControl": "INITIALIZE_FROM_SOURCE",
                  "RateControlMode": "CBR",
                  "CodecProfile": "MAIN",
                  "Telecine": "NONE",
                  "MinIInterval": 0,
                  "AdaptiveQuantization": "HIGH",
                  "CodecLevel": "AUTO",
                  "FieldEncoding": "PAFF",
                  "SceneChangeDetect": "ENABLED",
                  "QualityTuningLevel": "SINGLE_PASS",
                  "FramerateConversionAlgorithm": "DUPLICATE_DROP",
                  "UnregisteredSeiTimecode": "DISABLED",
                  "GopSizeUnits": "FRAMES",
                  "ParControl": "INITIALIZE_FROM_SOURCE",
                  "NumberBFramesBetweenReferenceFrames": 2,
                  "RepeatPps": "DISABLED",
                  "DynamicSubGop": "STATIC"
                }
              },
              "AfdSignaling": "NONE",
              "DropFrameTimecode": "ENABLED",
              "RespondToAfd": "NONE",
              "ColorMetadata": "INSERT"
            },
            "Extension": ".mp4",
            "NameModifier": "overlay_video"
          }
        ],
        "OutputGroupSettings": {
          "Type": "FILE_GROUP_SETTINGS",
          "FileGroupSettings": {
            "Destination": "s3://XXXXXXX/files/"
          }
        }
      }
    ],
    "AdAvailOffset": 0,
    "MotionImageInserter": {
      "InsertionMode": "MOV",
      "Input": "s3://XXXXXXX/converted_overlay.mov",
      "Offset": {
        "ImageX": 0,
        "ImageY": 0
      },
      "Playback": "ONCE"
    },
    "Inputs": [
      {
        "FilterEnable": "AUTO",
        "PsiControl": "USE_PSI",
        "FilterStrength": 0,
        "DeblockFilter": "DISABLED",
        "DenoiseFilter": "DISABLED",
        "TimecodeSource": "EMBEDDED",
        "FileInput": "s3://XXXXXXX/sample_video.mp4"
      }
    ]
  },
  "StatusUpdateInterval": "SECONDS_60"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

After some trial and error, I found out that there is a requirement for the motion graphic overlay file to be in pixel format `argb`.

The error message here tells you that you mov file has a different pixel format. If you have `ffmpeg` installed on your machine, you can run the following command to convert your file to the right format:

```
ffmpeg -i your_input_file.mov -sn -dn -an -vcodec qtrle -pix_fmt argb -f mov your_output_file.mov
```

- `-i` is to specify the input file,
- `-sn` removes any subtitle track
- `-dn` removes any data track
- `-an` removes any audio track
- `-vcodec qtrle` sets "Quicktime Animation" as the codec
- `-pix_fmt argb` sets `argb` as the pixel data format
- `-f mov` sets `mov` as the output file container type.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks, I will try it

Comment: Thanks, @Tiziano Coroneo, I tried, the job runs without error. But the output doesn't include the overlay, I explained more detail in question.

Comment: Can you post the full configuration json of the mediaConvert job?